# How to get passed schedule list(Process Builder) - Flow Interview

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, scheduled

I need to get what the completed, deleted and failed schedule list which is run based scheduled Process Builder action.

I tried using the flow interview objects but in that, we can only able to get the list of schedule that is going to happen.